# What is the significance of fields in Meta Class of UserCreationForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, metaclass

I am a Django noob and I have a question I know the people of this beautiful community can help me answer.
In my Django project I have created a custom user (using AbstractUser) having a custom field 'number'.
The custom user model is named AdminUser.

```
#models.py
class AdminUser(AbstractUser):
   number = PhoneNumberField(blank=False, unique=True, editable=True)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['number']

   objects = AdminUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.username
```

I have assigned a custom UserAdmin for this class

```
#admin.py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = AdminUserChangeForm
    add_form = AdminUserCreationForm
    model = AdminUser
    list_display = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'number']
    list_filter = ['is_superuser', 'first_name']

    """Fields when editing users"""
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        ('Primary Contact', {'fields': ('number',)}),
    )

    """Fields when adding new user"""
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        ('New User Credentials', {'fields': ('number', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
    )
```

And forms like so

```
#forms.py
class AdminUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = AdminUser
        #how does 'fields' below affect the form structure?? 
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'number')


class AdminUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AdminUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'number')
```

My question is how do the 'fields' tuple in Meta class in forms.py affect the structure of the creation and change forms?
When I remove or add an element to the fields tuple there is no difference in these forms in Django admin.
It is the fieldsets and add_fieldsets in CustomUserAdmin that effects the form structure.
So what is the use of fields in the Meta class of forms.py?
Are they just for informatic use?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if your `CustomerAdmin` was not inherited from `UserAdmin`, it would work as expected. The ModelAdmin fields you use will override the `fields` specified on the form.

If you use ModelForms *outside of the admin*, it will also work as you expect, but the admin is kind of an old kludgy thing and might not always work the way you think.

In general, the `fields` specifies which fields from the model to show, as you suggest, and it will work in most cases (just not in this one).

Comment: moreover, it seems the `CustomUserAdmin` not registered.

Comment: I think it is, since they say that changing the `add_fieldsets` etc. changes the form.